# When to free memory?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm working on a lexer / parser combination with Bison and Flex, and am slightly worried about memory leaks.

The grammar is quite a simple one, and (so far) I have been able to get away with the following definition:

```
#define YYSTYPE char const *
```

In Flex, when I read a string, I allocate enough memory for that string and then copy it into `yylval`.  As far as I know, this is quite standard practice.

However, I can't find any docs anywhere that tell me when I should free the memory in yylval.

Does Bison handle it automatically for me?  Do I have to do it at the end of my action?  Or when else should I be doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time a right-hand-side is evaluated, the RHS items on the stack (i.e., `$1`, `$2`, etc.) need to be deallocated or copied to `$$`.

After the reduction action executes, the stack pointer is decremented by the number of symbols on the RHS and `$$` becomes the top-most item, so anything left on the stack will be lost or clobbered by subsequent shifts onto the stack.

Also, you might be better off using a structure for the stack type that contains the token text string and its integer token value.

Comment: Not forgetting that:  `non_terminal: nt1 { frag1 } nt2 { frag2 };` keeps $2 as the result of frag1 available to frag2.

Comment: I don't actually parse many (if any) integers - these are all quoted strings.

Comment: Yes, but internally, the parser keeps each token and nonterminal symbol as an integer on the parsing stack. The lexer (`yylex`) returns an integer token code, even if there is additional info for each token (i.e., the token text).